# Facebook Sharing: How to update the OG tags when loading a page using AJAX

Tags: facebook, jquery, share

I've got a site that loads all 'pages' and 'content' using 100% AJAX. I'm using jQuery to handle the AJAX loads.

The problem I'm having is that I want to include a FB share link for the individual project pages (see link below):

http://www.concrete.ca/#!/work_project.php?project_ID=32

So, the idea is that when each project is loaded in via AJAX I'll then use jQuery (when the doc is .ready) to update the OG meta tags that reside in the index.php page. I've given each of the FB OG meta's an ID that corresponds to it's purpose (e.g. FB_title). So, here's the OG meta's that reside in the HEAD of index.php:

```
<meta id="FB_title" property="og:title" content="Concrete Design Communications" /> 
<meta id="FB_description" property="og:description" content="Internationally acclaimed Toronto-based brand design practice serving a variety of sectors including telecom, luxury retail, fashion, cosmetics, hospitality, publishing, as well as furniture and product design." /> 
<meta id="FB_image" property="og:image" content="http://www.concrete.ca/images/LOGO.png" />
```

And then when each of the project pages loads in via AJAX, I want to update the 'content' 
attribute of the meta tags. Along these lines:

```
$('#FB_title').attr('content', 'Concrete Design: <? print $GA_project_name; ?>');
```

The problem is that when I run that code I get a "Parse error." Anyone else run into this? What is the best way to update FB OG meta's when loading pages in via AJAX?

I've looked throught the FB dev docs but there doesn't seem to be anything that address' this.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook's linter does not run any javascript.  So you'll have to be sure to serve off the correct content when facebook comes to grab it.

Here's what you'll need to do.  Two options.  Either work and have been proved to work with other production websites.  J

- Specify the AJAX url in the Like plugin  code. Have a special handler on your web server when it sees requests from Facebook's linter. The user agent of the scraper is: `"facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)"`. Then your server can parse the hash bang and serve the specific og meta tags for that content. This is called URL Rewriting and can be done via .htaccess.
- Specify a canonical URL in the Like plugin code. That canonical URL is unique for each piece of content that can be displayed, maybe a direct call to `http://www.concrete.ca/work_project.php?project_ID=32` (without the hash bang) that renders out the correct og: meta tags.